# Argument of \@xnext has an extra }

Tags: tables

I simply generated the following table from [here](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables) website so syntax-wise it should be correct.

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 & Frames with Obstacle(s) & Number of Obstacle(s) & Distance to Obstacle(s) m & False Detections & Percentage \\ \hline
Real-Data Medium-2 & 10900 & 1 & 200 & 6101 & 55.97 \\ \hline
Real-Data Easy-2 & 4705 & 2 & 500 & 8 & 0.17 \\ \hline
Real-Data Easy-1 & 8010 & 1 & 500 & 7 & 0.09 \\ \hline
Simulation-Data Easy & 2000 & 1 & 100-200 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
Simulation-Data Medium & 2000 & 2 & 100-200 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
Simulation-Data Hard & 2000 & 5 & 100-200 & 116 & 5.8 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{False Detections in every data stream when the Intensity Threshold
Value is set to 170}
\label{os_thr70}
\end{table}
```

However I get tons of errors for this simple piece of code, which left me in doubt. I think LateX is bugged or somehow is messed up. I copied one of the errors as you can see it in the title.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How about wrapping this inside a `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}` ... `\end{document}`?

Comment: I have no errors on compiling. The only problem is the table can't fit the margins